# "git config --edit --global" says - command not found

Tags: git, command-line, git-bash

I have been trying to access the Eclipse IDE through the above command line (after setting my username and email with `git config --global user.name` and `git config --global user.email` respectively) and every time I do, it shows me the following on the command line:

[image: It keeps saying "command not found"].

I have tried making changes through environmental variables but it still did not work.

Comment: It would probably be a good idea for you to include the commands and the error messages in your question as formatted text [instead of posting a picture of them](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3890632).

Answer (score 4):

It's not a problem with git itself. The problem in on the first line in your picture
`git config --global core.editor "code --wait --new-window"`

It changes your default editor, but `code` is not reachable. Verify if you have Visual studio code installed, or change the editor to something else. You shouldn't need such heavy editor to edit your gitconfig to be honest.

If you are sure that you have VSC installed, check your PATH variable
`echo $PATH` to find out if the path to VSC is there.

Comment: I do not want to use visual studio code, i want to use eclipse and when i was installing git, i specified that i wanted eclipse ide but it's still giving me these problems.

Comment: @ekeneuzodinma As this answer points out, you've _changed_ your configuration to ask to use the program "code" (which is Visual Studio Code). That's what the first line in your screenshot was doing. If you didn't know that's what it was doing, then be thankful that it wasn't something worse, and be more careful running commands you don't understand.

Comment: You can run another `git config --global core.editor "<insert your desired editor here, not including the angle brackets>"` to replace the `code --wait --new-window` setting.